# What is horizontal about a horizontal symmetry?

Tags: particle-physics

When studying a seminal paper in flavor physics, [Mass Matrix Models](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9212278) (released in 1992), I came across the term, a *horizontal symmetry*. Googling around I saw this was (is?) indeed a commonly used term. They appear to define this symmetry in the context of the Standard Model as,
\begin{equation}
Q \rightarrow L Q , \bar{d} \rightarrow R _d \bar{d} , \bar{u} \rightarrow R _u \bar{u} , \phi \rightarrow P \phi 
\end{equation}
where $L,R_u,R_d$ mix between the generations of quarks and $P$ mixes between the color singlet doublet scalars in the model.

It just seems to be the most general flavor symmetry assuming $3$ generations and consistent with gauge symmetry. Is there something that I am missing about the meaning of a horizontal symmetry and in what sense is it "horizontal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textbook An Introductory Course of Particle Physics by Palash B. Pal offers a (slightly unsatisfactory) answer. The author writes that

> Such symmetris are often called *horizontal symmetries*. The name is a pictorial reminder to the list of quark fields in Eq. 17.1: transformations in this group act horizontally in this arrangement.

I don't have the book and the page  with Eq. 17.1 isn't avaiable in the preview, but I imagine it's simply a horizontal list of quarks e.g. $u$, $c$, $t$. I find this quite tenuous, and wonder whether there is another deeper reason.