# Horizontal Gauge Symmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gauge-theory, beyond-the-standard-model

Some physics literature says Horizontal Symmetry of gauge theory, such as [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789814335614_0055), available also at [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1833).

What does this Horizontal Symmetry of gauge theory or Horizontal gauge group mean? Does that mean the symmetry group in the same energy scale (horizontal, not go up or down of an energy scale)?

People speak about the Horizontal Symmetry, such as in the Symmetry for 3 family of leptons and quarks.

Comment: This may be related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/206521/42982 but not enough to answer fully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Horizontal symmetries or family symmetries** are various discrete, global, or local symmetries between (three) **families or generations** of quarks and leptons  in particle physics.

See References in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_symmetries.

**Horizontal gauge symmetries** would be **Horizontal symmetries** that are local and gauged.

Comment: I hope there is a better answer, thanks. But I can accept it if no more better answers.